# SearchView widget collapses because of change in Menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-menu

My app uses several fragments to create a master/detail layout. These fragments have certain `MenuItems`. The Activity also has some global `MenuItems` such as Search. When I want to search, I need to be able to change the left (master) fragment to view my search results. But when I click the Search icon in the actionbar, the searchview expands but collapses immediatly because the new fragment causes the Menu to alter.

For certain reasons I can't create another Activity to search in. Does somebody know how I can avoid the SearchView Widget in my actionbar to collapse when a new Fragment adds/removes items from the Menu?